# JPA parent/child relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, parent-child

Using JPA (Hibernate) I'm trying to implement the below relationship and was wondering if others have any suggestions about the best approach:

```
@Entity(name="SOMETHING")
public class Something {
    List<MetaDatum> metaData;
}

@Entity(name="SOMETHING_COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT")
public class SomethingCompletelyDifferent {
    List<MetaDatum> metaData;
}

@Entity(name="META")
public class MetaDatum {

}
```

Basically it's `n` completely unrelated objects which each have a collection of common child objects; simple to implement in the object model, slightly more troublesome in the database!

I'm sure this must be a common occurrence but I've had trouble finding any example implementations since I don't really know the right search terms.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a case for the `@OneToMany` annotation on the `metaData` fields in your `Something` and `SomethingCompletelyDifferent` (`SCD`)entities. Where you go from there depends.

Since `Something` and `SCD` do not have a common ancestor, you cannot simply make the relation bidirectional and use a join column.

There are several solutions, so you will have to decide depending on your actual use case.

- simply stick with the unidirectional relation, if you do not need to traverse from `MetaDatum` to it's parent entities. The relation will be mapped with join tables by hibernate.
- make separate `MetaDatum1` and `MetaDatum2` entities that can have bidirectional relations to their respective parent objects.
- create a common ancestor for the two parent entities, containing a bidirectional relation to `MetaDatum`
- create two entities, each encapsulating a `List<MetaDatum>`, tailored for a bidirectional relation to your `Something` and `SCD` entities

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for the info!  I think the first of your solutions fits most comfortably with what I'm developing since I don't need the relationship to be bi-directional and there are conceivably over ten objects requiring this relationship.

Comment: I would a fifth option which is to have multiple owner fields with a JoinTable associated with each one.